# When to 'implement' interface in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, class, interface

My question might be stupid, but i would like to get some clarity on this. As per my understanding, in angular we use interface to give idea about the data structure. So suppose we have an array of data of persons, we create an interface like

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: string
 }
```

And we can directly import this to our ts file and assign the type like

```
export class ComponentName implements OnInit {
data: Person[];
constructor() {}
ngOnInIt(){}
}
```

I totally understand this. But my confusion is, when do we 'implement' interface. I saw examples like

```
export class ComponentName implements OnInit, Person {
data: Person[];
constructor() {}
ngOnInIt(){}
}
```

Any help would be appreciatable. Thank you

Comment: In letter options, now your ComponentName MUST HAVE name and age fields ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In letter options, now your `ComponentName` MUST HAVE name and age fields ;)

so construct like this `class X implements Y` says literally that `X` is an `Y`

Also keep in mind that in typescript declarations does not matter, but actual structure, so even without `implements Person` delcaration, if `ComponentName` would have `name` and `age` fields, `person:Person=this` would still be valid.

Comment: So in first case, ie if we need to just assign the structure, we don't have to implement interface, we can directly import it and use?. Can you please explain further?

Comment: `data: Person[];` says that `data` is an array of `Person`. `ComponentName implements  Person`  Means that `ComponentName` class is a `Person`